# CSS3 Animation-fill-mode property

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I'm creating an effect where text slides into the window and stays there after the animation ends. I've been able to get the animation to work on 1 piece of the text, but for some reason the 2nd piece is not working.

Please see my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9fpryou8/

Thanks in advance.

```
figure h2.world {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 61%;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 7em;
  color: white;
  font-family: Paytone One, Verdana, sans-serif;
  transform: translateX(300%);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px black;

  -moz-animation-name: slideWorld;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1.4s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  -webkit-animation-name: slideWorld;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  animation-name: slideWorld;
  animation-iteration-count: 1.4;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.world`, replace

```css
animation-iteration-count: 1.4;
```

with

```css
animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

```css
figure {
    height: 98vh;
    background-color: grey;
}
figure h2.hello {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 39%;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-family: Paytone One, Verdana, sans-serif;
  transform: translateX(-400%);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px black;
  
  -moz-animation-name: slideHello;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  -webkit-animation-name: slideHello;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  animation-name: slideHello;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

figure h2.world {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 61%;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-family: Paytone One, Verdana, sans-serif;
  transform: translateX(300%);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px black;
  
  -moz-animation-name: slideWorld;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1.4s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  -webkit-animation-name: slideWorld;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  animation-name: slideWorld;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/**** Display Hello on Load ****/
@-moz-keyframes slideHello {
  to {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-39%);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideHello {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-39%);
  }
}
@keyframes slideHello {
  to {
   transform: translateX(-39%);
  }
}

/**** Display World on Load ****/
@-moz-keyframes slideWorld {
  to {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-61%);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideWorld {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-61%);
  }
}
@keyframes slideWorld {
  to {
   transform: translateX(-61%);
  }
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <h2 class="hello">Hello</h2>
  <h2 class="world">World</h2>
</figure
```

Or simple delete it: the initial value of `animation-iteration-count` is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typing mistake

change `animation-iteration-count: 1.4;` to `animation-iteration-count: 1;`

then it should work